# Linux or Windows on the go to change permissions

Tags: permissions, liveusb

Can I boot into Linux or Windows on the go and change the permissions for one folder in Windows? Would those permissions be reflected on the OS once I booted as a normal user?

As it is I can't paste some files into a directory that asks for admin rights because I'm a standard user.

Using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever changes you do to the hard disk are permanent.

However, avoid modifying a Linux disk with Windows, and vice versa.

Comment: Ok. What if I use a Windows live USB to change the default Windows drive? What would be the steps to perform such modification on the installed OS?

Comment: Modifying files/folders by two so different operating systems is asking for trouble.

Comment: The way I personally have dealt with this in the past (MANY OSs, not just two) was to create a fat32 partition for my "folder" and share there.  Fat32 is too stupid (which I love) to deal with file permissions or anything else.. you just need to be REAL careful that you don't pull the plug while writing the the file system as there is no journal.  You can use a junction through disk manager to mount this in windows and the `mount` command in Linux.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't have access to admin group, so actions would be performed under standard user.

Comment: Within the Live environment, you have administrator powers.

Comment: Yes, but consider this:
1- Running OS on drive C:
2- Plugging in the other drive (drive D:) with the OS I don't have admin rights.
3- Can I, while running from OS on C, set the permissions for that folder on drive D:?